# Compile in Code::Blocks like in command line

Tags: c++, command-line, compilation, codeblocks

I am attempting to test a program for a colleague that was not written in an IDE.  When we go to run it, something goes wrong and we are having a heck of a time trying to figure out what it is.

I got the bright idea to compile and run the code in Code::Blocks (as we are running it in ubuntu) so we could watch what it was doing internally as it was running.  The code compiles when you type in:

```
g++ fe_cmd_arg2_new.c -pthread K_drv_21.cc urg_drv_425.cc o_structures.c ri,cc star_cam_374.cpp com_Unit.o
```

but not when it is compiled in Code::Blocks.  How would I compile in Code::Blocks like I would on the command line?

Comment: Are you sure you posted your correct command line instruction? You seem to have `n` number of `program.cc` files there.

Comment: its just to keep things generic.  each is an individual piece of code.

Comment: Please post your *actual* instructions, your attempt to  oversimlpify things simply complicates it that bit more.Generic Programming is good not generic Q's.Your Q is specific so be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, missed the main question: how would you compile as-in code blocks. That's probably just adding in `-g` to build debug symbols plus likely `-O2` to optimise the code. But if you're debugging it might help to leave off the optimisation switch.

However unless you're then able to debug in an IDE you could try the gdb debugger:

- add `-g` to your compile line to build in debug symbols (if you're compiling and linking separately then to all lines including the link line)
- run the program with gdb

  ```
  gdb ./a.out
  run <command line args>
  ```

Unfortunately gdb is command-line and difficult to approach but you should try `bt` to print a stack trace, then you can `print <var>` to dump state, etc.

Comment: Alright, we're going to try gdb.  The only hang up is whether or not we are successful in figuring out how to use everything. Thanks for the idea!